# CSS rotation: Flash not rotating

Tags: css, rotation, flash-video

I have a parent div with a flash movie in it. 
I rotate the parent div, so I expect that the flash movie is also rotated.

Unfortunatly this doesn't happen. The flash movie has no rotation.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>
    .rotate
    {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 250px;
        width:800px;
        height: 800px;
        background-color: #f00; 


        -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
        transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="rotate">
    <h1>Youtube Flash Video:</h1>
    <object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/KMU0tzLwhbE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/KMU0tzLwhbE?version=3&amp;hl=en_US" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is how it looks like in the browser

[image]

Do you know how I can get this flash movie rotating with its parent?

Thanks a lot!
Vincent

Comment: I don't know about flash, but I have seen the HTML5 `<video>` tag successfully rotated, so that may be an option for you instead.

Comment: Yes indeed, but I have to use videos from a Youtube channel and I have to support IE8 and IE7. Thanks :)

Comment: I thought YouTube was doing html5 video now? anyway the rotation code in your example won't work in IE7/8 either, so I assumed that wasn't an issue for you. If you could use html5 video for newer browsers and you're not going to rotate in IE7/8, then you could use the flash as a fallback for IE7/8, and let the other browsers do the rotation on the video element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new way of youtube embedding solved my problem.

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

Comment: Can you please show us how did you rotate your swf using the new way of youtube embedding?